# Should I use ejb @Schedule annotation over schedule executor

Tags: ejb, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm writing a service that will call REST service every x seconds. I could do that with EJB @Schedule annotation as well as with ScheduledExecutorService.

which one is better to use? and why?

Comment: I don't really know the ScheduledExecutorService, but Schedule is the explicit way in the EJB spec to define a timer. So I would think that it's the way to go if you are using EJB anyway. Note that Schedule is calendar based, so you can say that the timer will start on every xth second of a minute, but it can be that between the last trigger of a minute and the first of the next the delay is different than x seconds. Also the timer is not guaranteed to be exact.

Comment: @jhyot ScheduledExecutorService is an ExecutorService that allows you to run a task after a delay or execute repeatedly with a fixed interval of time in between each execution.

Thank for the explanation. I will use Schedule annotation intead of ScheduledExecutorService :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing an EJB application, you should use `Schedule` - the EJB spec demands that EJBs [should not use threads directly](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html), and says that doing so may cause errors in the container, as well as preventing the container from managing resources efficiently.
In exchange, with `Schedule` you get the benefits of container management and EJB services.